# How to format output from a program spawned from a expect script

Tags: tcl, expect

I am writing a load testing script for radius server using tcl and expect.
I am invoking radclient, that comes inbuild with the radius server, from my script on remote server.
scripts does following:

take remote server IP
   - spawn ssh to remote server
   - invoke radclient
   - perform load test using radclient commands
   - need to collect the result from the output (as shown in the sample output) into a variable
   - Extract authentication/sec as Transaction per second (TPS) from output or variable from previous step

Need help on last two steps:

Sample output from radclient:

```
*--> timetest 20 10 2 1 1
Cycles: 10, Repetitions: 2, Requests per Cycle: 10
Starting User Number: 1, Increment: 1
Current Repetition Number=1
Skipping Accounting On Request
Total Requests=100, Total Responses=100, Total Accepts=0 Total Not Accepts=100
   1: Sending 100 requests and getting 100 responses took 449ms, or 0.00 authentications/sec
Current Repetition Number=2
Skipping Accounting On Request
Total Requests=100, Total Responses=100, Total Accepts=0 Total Not Accepts=100
   2: Sending 100 requests and getting 100 responses took 471ms, or 0.00 authentications/sec
```

Expected Output:

```
TPS achieved = 0
```

Answer (score 0):

You might use something like this:

```
expect -re {([\d.]+) authentications/sec}
set authPerSec $expect_out(1,string)
puts "TPS achieved = $authPerSec"
```

However, that's not to say that the information extracted is the *right* information. For example, when run against your test data it is likely to come unstuck as there are two places where you have `authentications/sec` due to all the repetitions; we don't account for that at all! More complex patterns might extract more information and so on.

```
expect {
    -re {([\d.]+) authentications/sec} {
        set authPerSec $expect_out(1,string)
        puts "TPS achieved #[incr count] = $authPerSec"
        exp_continue
    }
    "bash$" {
        # System prompt means stop expecting; tune for what you've got...
    }
}
```

Doing the right thing can be complex sometimes…